# Use Django Call Command With Greater Than Sign As Argument

Tags: python, django, arguments

Is there a way to pass ">" as an argument when using `call_command('dumpdata','>','db.json')`

When using this command from the terminal as `python manage.py dumpdata > db.json` everything works as expected, but when trying to use it programatically is when the issue occurs.

Namely

> LookupError: No installed app with label '>'.

The specific question is "how do I use the `>` argument in the `call_command` function."

But more generally, is there some fundamental rule that i am misunderstanding about handling this symbol in the `call_command` function?

Comment: right. I know i can use sub processes. (and probably will end up doing so) but it would be pretty useful to know what the deal with the call_command function is . and how to pass this as an argument. Thanks. @JoranBeasley

Comment: it passes it as an argument ... the string ">" ... which manage.py dumpdata interprets as a table name ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you use subprocess PIPE to redirect your output ... you can definately pass `>` as a command to subprocess call but it will be interpreted as a literal `'>'` rather than a redirect ... so it is trying to dumpdata for a table named ">" which clearly does not exist in your database

If you want to simply output your dumpdata to a file you can instead use the `-o` flag (see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/django-admin/#cmdoption-dumpdata-output)

```
call_command('dumpdata','-o','db.json')
```

or use output redirection directly as seen here (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/django-admin/#output-redirection)

```
with open('/path/to/db.json',"wb") as f:
    management.call_command('dumpdata', stdout=f)
```

Comment: Thanks. The -o flag was what I was missing.